# Android Studio Protocol family unavailable error

Tags: android, android-studio

When I launch android studio for first time, see this error.how can I solve this problem ?

[image]

Comment: why no answer to this question? Who downvoted this question? even i have the same issue since last month and couldnt work on studio, plz answer to this questio if anyone knows ...

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am also faced the same issue, then i added my application gradle manually to my application(i.e,select right side gradle option in studio and click plus button in top most left corner then choose your gradle file).Now error remain same but i can able to run my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

Setting _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable to make Java use IPv4.

`_JAVA_OPTIONS = -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Comment: Edit you answer. And include some images for the solution if possible.